# I need to change my Joomla Template header to transparent

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0

i have a small problem with my joomla site header and i would like to make it transparent so that the images under this one can be seen through . the the thing is i don't know how to do it can you kindly assist me on this one.

i have attached the image to specify the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPTKO.jpg)

Kindly assist

Comment: Please check this useful post: https://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using css. Add your own selector with the below code.

```
element_selector {
    opacity: 0.5; /* Max value =1 ; Min Value = 0 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

You Can also use

```
element_selector {
    background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.3) /* Green background with 30% opacity */
}
```